# ASP.NET Membership Provider ResetPassword isn't working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have encountered a very strange issue.  Whenever I use the .NET membership provider to reset a password, it generates strange characters, which don't represent the password at all.

An example of the password it generates is:

> 쥳⮚聙蟐֡ᑡ壈I#BAhy(ox32+y*

It does this on every password.  Has anyone seen this before or know a fix?

Thanks,
George

Comment: Where is this value?  In the database?

Comment: The value in the database is an encrypted string, it resolves to this.

Comment: I was going to say that if you are looking at the value in the database, it is likely encrypted, but its obvious that I don't need to say that :)

Comment: Do you have `enablePasswordRetrieval="false"` in your web.config? If so, the passwords are not decryptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the Password in the membership provider was mix matched with the ASP.NET config password storage type, so when the password was being pulled out, it was attempting to decrypt it in the wrong manner.